# Adding array of values and to highlight all the value in array using ng-class

Tags: css, angularjs

I have 2 ng-repeat, and on selecting the inner index, the outer index should highlight. I need to add a colour to a highlighted values and I am using multiple values (i.e., an array of values).

On clicking inner ng-repeat I am trying to push the value to the scope,

```
$scope.setData = function(isSelected) {
    $scope.isSelected.push(isSelected);
    console.log(isSelected + " " + $scope.isSelected);
}

<div class="row>"
<div ng-repeat="out in outs track by $index" >
      <a href=""
      ng-class="getClass($index)">{{out.label}}</a></div></div>
      <!-- </div> -->
</div>

<div ng-repeat="out in outs track by $index">
    <div ng-if="out_index== $index">
        <div>{{out.label}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <!--  <div class="jumbotron vcenter">  -->
            <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="inner in out.inners | orderBy: 'id' " >
                <li class="list-group-item cursorPointer">
                    <img src="{{inner.location}}" alt="{{inner.description}}" title="{{inner.description}}" ng-dblclick="setData($parent.$index)"/>
                    <div>
                        <font>{{inner.description}}</font>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- </div>   -->
    </div>
</div>

$scope.isSelected = [];
$scope.getClass = function(ind) {
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.isSelected.length; i++) {
        console.log("Length " + $scope.isSelected.length + " Scope >>" + $scope.isSelected[i] + " Index " + ind);
        if($scope.isSelected[i] == ind) {
            return "selected";
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you only ever iterate `isSelected` once - if the condition fails you return an empty string..

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to highlight the outer ng-repeat on selecting all the inner ng-repeat using $parent.$index. So I am using array to hold the value and trying the all the values of outer to get highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($scope.isSelected.indexOf(ind) !== -1) {
    return "selected";
}
else {
    return "";
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The *for* loop is terminating at the first iteration. Remove `else` and `return ""` after the loop:

```
 $scope.getClass = function (ind) {
     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.isSelected.length; i++) {
          if ($scope.isSelected[i] == ind) {
                return "selected";
          }
      }
      return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Prem!! I used indexOf to check but I just want to know is it required to iterate (or) is it fine to use indexOf for checking existing value in array. I am new to angularjs, please guide.

Comment: indexOf is an another option to check whether the array contains the value/object. IndexOf is better way than iterate.